# Maximum static friction while pressing an object to the wall

Tags: friction

[image]

In the picture above, the $m$ object is not moving. If we increase $F$ force, will the ***maximum*** static friction increase also?

If I use $$(f_s)_{max} = \mu_s N$$ formula, then the answer is yes ($N=F$), but someone says:

> You shouldn't use this formula for this situation (pressing object on a *vertical* wall). This is an exception and maximum static friction is equal to static friction and constant here.

I agree that static friction is constant because the only vertical force (except friction) is weight (mg) and it doesn't change but about **maximum** static friction I can't agree with him.

Who is wrong?

I know this is a simple question but I couldn't figure it out. Sorry! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and 'someone' are arguing at cross purposes, since you are talking about different meanings of the phrase 'maximum static friction'.

You are using the phrase to mean the maximum force that friction could cause to oppose the movement of the object. In that sense, the maximum is proportional to the applied force F, and so would increase linearly (to a first approximation) with F.

'Someone' is taking 'maximum static friction' to mean the actual maximum force imposed by friction in the scenario shown, which remains mg even if you increase the magnitude of F.

The difference between the two interpretations would become apparent in either of two scenarios. One would be if you reduced the magnitude of F to the point at which the 'maximum static friction' in your sense became less than mg, in which case the object would slide down the wall. The other would be if you imposed an additional force pulling the object downwards, in which case the force of friction would increase to oppose the movement until the 'maximum static friction' limit was reached.

All in all I think your use of the term 'maximum static friction' is more in line with its general meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the maximum static friction will increase, but friction can't cause an object to accelerate so the frictional force will always be equal to the weight, $mg$. This is because $F_r \le \mu N$, so can take any value less than $\mu N$ in order to balance the weight.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you increase $F$ you increase the maximum static friction force. It does not, however, increase the actual static friction force.

I think the person  is using the term “maximum static friction force” when the person really means the actual static friction force $f_s$. The actual static friction force is constant simply because the force it opposes, $mg$, happens to be constant. In examples involving horizontal surfaces the force opposed by static friction is typically a variable depending on the applied horizontal force which makes the static friction force also a variable up to the maximum possible static friction force.

In this example the maximum possible static friction force is $uF$. That could be reached if, for example, you gradually suspended additional weight to the existing weight. As you add weight the actual static friction force increases to oppose the additional weight  until it reaches the maximum static friction force, at which point impending motion will occur.

Hope this helps.